# Unable to get XML attribute using Go

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I wrote the following code and XML file to try to reproduce the situation I am dealing with- I am able to retrieve every other tag's data except TEST, and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated!

For example, in the below code I am able to get the data for the ST tag but not the TEST tag.

XML Code

```xml
<R>
<ST N="Hello" />
<JK M="Hello World">
<TEST NM="Got Test Tag" />
</JK>
</R>
```

Go code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

type test struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"R"`
    AllTest []testTest `xml:"TEST"`
    ST []testST `xml:"ST"`
}
type testST struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ST"`
    STVal string `xml:"N,attr"`
}
type testTest struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"TEST"`
    testVal string `xml:"NM,attr"`
}

func makeCharsetReader(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    if charset == "Windows-1252" {
        return charmap.Windows1252.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unknown charset: %s", charset)
}

func parse(testPath string) {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open(testPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    var parseDoc test
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
    decoder.CharsetReader = makeCharsetReader
    err = decoder.Decode(&parseDoc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(parseDoc.AllTest)
    fmt.Println(parseDoc.ST)
}

func main() {
    filePath := "absolute_path_to_the_xml_file"
    parse(filePath)
}
```

The output I get is

`[]
[{{ ST} Hello}]`

The output for the ST tag is as expected, but why do I get no data for the TEST tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TEST` element in your example is a child of `JK`, but your struct definitions expect it to be a child of `R`. Try the struct definitions shown below.

```
type test struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"R"`
    JK      JK       `xml:"JK"`
    ST      []testST `xml:"ST"`
}

type JK struct {
    AllTest []testTest `xml:"TEST"`
}

type testST struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ST"`
    STVal   string   `xml:"N,attr"`
}

type testTest struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"TEST"`
    TestVal string   `xml:"NM,attr"`
}
```